# Append non-breaking space behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, append

Why is that code like `$('#display').append('&nbsp &nbsp dogs');` appends "&nbsp &nbsp dogs" while `$('#display').append('&nbsp &nbsp dogs <br/>');` (or adding any html tag) appends just "dogs" after two spaces (as expected)? Does jQuery not recognise '&nbsp' as an html entity? Can I somehow force treating it like html?

```js
$('#display').append('&nbsp &nbsp dogs</br>');
$('#display').append('&nbsp &nbsp dogs <span>hi</span>');
$('#display').append('</br>');
$('#display').append('&nbsp &nbsp dogs');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: use `&nbsp;` (missed the `;`)

Comment: @Dekel, I see, so this difference I'm dealling with is just a matter of browser's (I use Chrome) auto-correction algorithm?

Comment: Probably yes. Chrome/webkit might cause the auto-correction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`append` function](http://api.jquery.com/append/) accept several content-types as the content to append

> htmlString, Element, Text, Array, jQuery.

When you use the a string with tags inside - jQuery treats the string as htmlString, and converts it to html:

```js
$('#display').append('<span style="color: red;">a &nbsp &nbsp dogs</sapn>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

This conversion also converts the typo `&nbsp` into `&nbsp;`

**However**, if jQuery doesn't recognize the string as html-string, it treats it as text (and creates a textNode with the string):

```js
$('#display').append('a &nbsp &nbsp dogs');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

> This behavior is the same in Chrome, Firefox, IE(11) and Safari.